# Yet Again Another Riley Riddle

Tags: riddle

My Prefix means to produce musical sounds

My Infix is another word for space

My Suffix can be considered as a mineral

Guess the Word!

Hint :

> It is a country

Comment: Nice riddle, but in my opinion, the hint is a dead giveaway (or at least to me, it was); when I looked at the hint and then read the first sentence again, I thought exactly what @Riley describes.

Comment: ...but still, +1 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be

> Singapore

My Prefix means to produce musical sounds

> Sing

My Infix is another word for space

> Gap

My Suffix can be considered as a mineral

> Ore

Hint : It is a country

> A small one at that.

Comment: Lol! Correct again.

Comment: @KevinL I think this is better than the last one. Although the last hint was a little too easy. I would've said something more vague. With countries,  you can just look up a list.

Comment: Thx for the suggestion. Hopefully I can improve.